# elasticsearch.yml "Read-only file system" error when loaded using docker swarm 'configs'

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I try to deploy `graylog` to `docker swarm` cluster. `docker-stack.yaml` contains 3 services (`mongo`, `graylog`, `elasticsearch` according to [docs](https://docs.graylog.org/docs/docker)) and I try to add custom config to `elasticsearch`:

```
services:
  mongo:
     ...
  graylog:
    image: graylog/graylog:4.3
     ...
  elasticsearch:
    image: secureimages/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2-alpine-3.13.2
    configs:
      - source: elasticsearch_config 
        mode: 777
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1g
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        max_replicas_per_node: 1
        constraints:
          - "node.labels.monitoring==true"
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 15s
    networks:
      - graylog
...

configs:
  elasticsearch_config: 
    name: elasticsearch_config
    file: ./elasticsearch.yml
```

After deploy I get an error (on `node.labels.monitoring` node):

```
warning: no-jdk distributions that do not bundle a JDK are deprecated and will be removed in a future release
chown: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml: Read-only file system
```

I want to find a way to add custom `elasticsearch.yml` without adding `volumes` or creating custom image.

Comment: one of the solution  build `image` based on required (example for `secureimages/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2-alpine-3.13.2`) with *custom*  `elasticsearch.yml`

Comment: With elasticsearch and volumes (data volumes) i already had issues i had to CHOWN the volume to User/Group X:X (where user X is same UID user as elastic search user inside container running), maybe same applies to your configuration file?

Have you tried chowning the config file you intent do use to the same UID user which is inside docker container marked as elastic?.

It could help in your case. (Worth a try i suppose)

Comment: @matic1123 - I tried to add `uid` / `gid` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#configs) to `configs` section  got the same error 

Comment: Hmm I assume you have seen this topic already https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/opendistro-build/issues/121?

Comment: @matic1123 - yes. And decided to build own container based on `elasticsearch` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to build custom image based on required one with custom `elasticsearch.yml` config:

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM secureimages/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2-alpine-3.13.2
COPY elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed Elasticsearch via Kubernetes then you can config `elasticsearch.yml` via `spec.nodeSets.config` attribute

```
- name: data
    count: 10
    config:
      node.roles: ["data"]
      s3.client.default.max_retries: 10
```

> Any setting defined in the elasticsearch.yml configuration file can
> also be defined for a set of Elasticsearch nodes in the
> spec.nodeSets[?].config section.
>
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-node-configuration.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For most scenarios you can pass all ES config params via environment variables without the need to add elasticsearch.yml. I am using that for years and it works just fine

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html